# Attempt to index a boolean value error when calling this function

Tags: lua

I get the attempt to index a boolean value error when calling this function:

```
M.on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
    if client.name == "tsserver" then
        client.resolved_capabilities.document_formatting = false
    end
    lsp_keymaps(bufnr)
    lsp_highlight_document(client)
end
```

Can anyone help me?

Edit:

I get the error on the second line here:

```
local opts = {
            on_attach = require("s3m.lsp.handlers").on_attach,
            capabilities = require("s3m.lsp.handlers").capabilities,
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`require("s3m.lsp.handlers")` returns `true` which is a boolean value. with `require("s3m.lsp.handlers").on_attach` you index that nil value which is an invalid operation in Lua.

For this to make sense your required script must return a value. In your case `M`

`require` returns `true` if the script is loaded successfully but does not return a non-nil value. Please read the manual to avoid such errors.

Comment: How does this one work then? https://github.com/samyhaff/Dotfiles/tree/master/nvim/.config/nvim/lua/user/lsp ? Look in lsp-installer for the require and in handlers.lua for the function itself

Comment: it returns `M` your script does not. would you please read my answer carefully and the manual befor asking futher questions? come on. my answer says the script must return a table for this to work, which handler.lua does... yours does not

Comment: But the github one is exactly the same can you please explain it to me or link a manual, i am so confused i've looked at them for an hour now and i see no difference.

Comment: at the end of  handler.lua you'll find `return M`. according to your error message you don't do this. I'm not sure what you don't understand here. if you want require to return a table that you may index the required script must return 
 that table value. otherwise it returns true which causes your error https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html